# Could the words "not effective" and "painstaking" be connected with the conjunction "but"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-structure

I wrote a sentence,

> "It was not always **effective** ***but***  **painstaking** and sometimes seemed like
>   waste of time."

and I wonder whether the words **"not effective"** and **"painstaking"** could  be connected with the conjunction **"but"**.

I'm confused because it seems quite natural for me at the first glance, but I learned that **"not effective"** and **"painstaking"** both also carry some negative meaning.

Does this sentence sound unnatural? Or maybe I should use other conjunction like, for instance, "and"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Our [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages contain advice on how to write a useful question. You might write: _"It was not always effective, but **it was** painstaking and sometimes seem**ed** like waste of time."_ (There is nothing negative about the word "painstaking." It means _showing diligent care and effort._ What dictionary told you that it has a negative connotation?)

Comment: Please try to include a detailed explanation of the meaning that you are trying to express with every post, in case it is not immediately clear.

Comment: *But* is used for contrast. Are you trying to contrast *effective* with *meticulous*? If so, try putting it the other way around: *It was painstaking but not always effective. Sometimes it seemed like a waste of time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you contrast two things using **but**, you generally want to give the impression that one of the concepts is stronger or more important. To do this, you put the emphasized concept **after** the but.

> It was hard work, but it was **worth the effort**.

In your sentence, you follow on with **sometimes it seems like a waste of time**, so you want to emphasize **not always effective**. It would therefore be better to write:

> It was painstaking but **not always effective**, and sometimes seemed like waste of time

**Not effective** is definitely negative: **painstaking** can be both negative and positive. Used with a **but** you are emphasizing the positive side. You could emphasize the negative side by using **and** rather than **but**.

> It was painstaking **and** not always effective, and sometimes seemed like waste of time